# Software to download silverlight videos in windows

Tags: windows, gratis, video, download-manager

Is there any tool to download silverlight videos in windows?

I would like following features if possible

1. Freeware / Open Source
2. Browser Support is not problem but I would like to be able to disable it if possible.

Comment: Can you tell some key features you want from that software?

Comment: @Cornelius has already given a good answer but we still would like to have a good question; to enhance your question please at least answer these questions in your question: what browser(s) do you need/want it to support? do you care about pricing? and do you care about open-source or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Orbit Downloader**](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/).

- freeware
- download videos from nay other sites
- supports many web browsers
- lightweight

[How to download](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/silverlight-downloader/download-videos-from-silverlight-free.htm):

- first run Grab++ from `Tools` menu
- start playing Silverlight videos
- select detected videos in Grab++ and start downloading

Here is a screenshot from its webpage:

[image]

Comment: Quoting another user who did not have enough rep to comment: *Do not use Orbital Downloader*. Read [Orbital Decay: the dark side of a popular file downloading tool](http://www.welivesecurity.com/2013/08/21/orbital-decay-the-dark-side-of-a-popular-file-downloading-tool/) about OD being an effective tool for Distributed Denial of Service (DDoS) attacks. Several download sites have removed it form their collections.
 

As a new user I cannot comment, so I must include this as an answer.

See welivesecurity and other sites available via a google search. O